# What is wrong here? Nothing is displayed on the screen

Tags: php, debugging

nothing is displayed at runtime. xdebug does not run. this simple example doesn't work.

```
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

abstract class Hello
{
    protected function hello();
}

class Helloworld extends Hello
{
    public $world;

    public function __construct($world){
        $this->world = $world;
    }

    public function hello() {
        echo 'Hello + '.$this->world;
    }
}

class Hiotherworld extends Hello
{
    public $world;

    public function __construct($world){
        $this->world = $world;
    }

    public function hello(){
        echo 'Hi + '.$this->world;
    }
}

$hello = new Helloworld("Earth");
$hello->hello();

$hi = new Hiotherworld("Mars");
$hi->hello();
```

Answer (score 2):

Fatal error: Non-abstract method Hello::hello() must contain body:
`protected function hello();`

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the visibility of a method in a subclass. You declared `hello()` as `protected` so it must be `protected` in sub classes as well.

I guess you wanted to declare it as `public` in `Hello` as protected makes no sense in this context. Also you missed the `abstract` keyword (Thanks @rNix) And you should move the declaration of `$world` to the base class:

Finally `Hello` should look like this:

```
abstract class Hello
{
    $protected $world;

    abstract public function hello();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it

```
abstract class Hello
{
    protected function hello(){}
}
```

working for me.